# Best way to convert list data to another with a desired format in c# using LINQ

Tags: c#, list, linq

How I need to insert a `chart` in my project and I use the `C3` library to do so, which expect a specific format to work.

I retrieve my data from my `database` and I get it into this format

```
{"TotalbeAbsencesDepartmentByReason":[
[   {"Label":"DQUA","Reason":"AUT","AbsNumber":1,"AbsenceHours":3.75},
    {"Label":"DQUA","Reason":"NOAUT","AbsNumber":1,"AbsenceHours":3.75},
    {"Label":"DQUA","Reason":"CM","AbsNumber":4,"AbsenceHours":32}
],
[{"Label":"DPRO","Reason":"AUT","AbsNumber":10,"AbsenceHours":43.9},{"Label":"DPRO","Reason":"CM","AbsNumber":18,"AbsenceHours":144}],
[{"Label":"DMAI","Reason":"AUT","AbsNumber":2,"AbsenceHours":1.6999999999999993}],
[{"Label":"DENG","Reason":"CM","AbsNumber":2,"AbsenceHours":16}]
]}
```

My expected format that I want to work on is :

```
"TotaleAbsDepartementByReason":
[
    {"Label":"DQUA","Aut":3.75,"NoAut":3.75,"CM":32},
    {"Label":"DPRO","Aut":43.9,"NoAut":0,"CM":144},
    {"Label":"DMAI","Aut":1.6999999999999993,"NoAut":0,"CM":0},
    {"Label":"DENG","Aut":0,"NoAut":0,"CM":16}
]
```

This is my solution it works perfectly, But I think that there is another way to proceed for better performance :

```
var DeptNames = TotalbeAbsencesDepartmentByReason.Select(b => b.Label).Distinct();
var TotaleAbsDepartementByReason = new List<AbsByReason>();
foreach (var name in DeptNames)
{
    var auth = TotalbeAbsencesDepartmentByReason.Where(a => a.Label == name && a.Reason == "AUT").FirstOrDefault();
    var noauth = TotalbeAbsencesDepartmentByReason.Where(a => a.Label == name && a.Reason == "NOAUT").FirstOrDefault();
    var cm = TotalbeAbsencesDepartmentByReason.Where(a => a.Label == name && a.Reason == "CM").FirstOrDefault();
    TotaleAbsDepartementByReason.Add(new AbsByReason
    {
        Aut = auth != null ? auth.AbsenceHours.Value : 0 ,
        CM = cm != null ? cm.AbsenceHours.Value : 0,
        NoAut = noauth != null ? noauth.AbsenceHours.Value : 0,
        Label = name
    });
}
```

Comment: Why exactly do you "think that there is another way to proceed for better performance"? What bottlenecks have you identified?

Comment: You can create a class with auth,noauth,Cm and use linq to create a list instead of using foreach loop.

Comment: Databases do *not* return JSON or nested objects. It looks like you used an ORM to load an entire graph and even converted the data to Json (why?). Then you try to flatten the data again and calculate aggregates.  It would be a *lot* better (1000x) if you created a query or view that performed the joins, aggregations you want in the database itself, not after the fact on the client. You can create entities that map on that view

Comment: _"Best way"_ is **subject to opinion** and sadly _off-topic_ for SO. [ask]

Comment: Your `TotalbeAbsencesDepartmentByReason` variable seems like a `List<Data>`, but your `JSON` looks like `List<List<Data>>`. Which one is it?

Answer (score 2):

You can organize your code slightly better, at-least from maintainability perspective, and removing some redundancies should hopefully offer some performance boost. Below is the refactored code

```
public class RowData {
    public string Label { get; set; }
    public string Reason { get; set; }
    public int AbsNumber { get; set; }
    public decimal? AbsenceHours { get; set; }
}

public class AbsByReason {
    public decimal Aut { get; set; }
    public decimal CM { get; set; }
    public string Label { get; set; }
    public object NoAut { get; set; }
}

public static IEnumerable<AbsByReason> TransformData(List<RowData> totalbeAbsencesDepartmentByReason) {
    return totalbeAbsencesDepartmentByReason
                .GroupBy(row => row.Label)
                .Select(XFormLabelGroupToAbsByReason);
}

private static AbsByReason XFormLabelGroupToAbsByReason(IEnumerable<RowData> labelGroup) {
    var reason = new AbsByReason();
    foreach (var rowData in labelGroup) {
        if (rowData.Reason == "AUT")
            reason.Aut = rowData.AbsenceHours ?? 0;
        else if (rowData.Reason == "NOAUT")
            reason.NoAut = rowData.AbsenceHours ?? 0;
        else if (rowData.Reason == "CM")
            reason.CM = rowData.AbsenceHours ?? 0;
    }
    return reason;
}
```

Let me explain what I have done. `GroupBy` is very helpful when using grouped data as you are in this case. Once you group your data, you only need to transform that group (instead of all the data in the list). You can use LINQ, but I would rather use a simple for-loop and if-else-if combination. I find it better to do things in single-pass than in multi-pass LINQ way even though you are pretty much talking about no more than 3 items in the list.

Answer (score 0):

One problem I see is that you traverse the original list three times with different filter predicates. Here's a way how you can get the same result with only one list traversal:

```
        var Depts = new Dictionary<string, AbsByReason>();
        foreach (var entry in TotalbeAbsencesDepartmentByReason)
        {
            AbsByReason abs;
            if (!Depts.TryGetValue(entry.Label, out abs))
                Depts[entry.Label] = abs = new AbsByReason() { Label = entry.Label };
            switch (entry.Reason)
            {
                case "AUT":
                    abs.Aut = entry.AbsenceHours.Value;
                    break;
                case "NOAUT":
                    abs.NoAut = entry.AbsenceHours.Value;
                    break;
                case "CM":
                    abs.CM = entry.AbsenceHours.Value;
                    break;
            }
        }
        var TotaleAbsDepartementByReason = Depts.Select(kvp => kvp.Value).ToList();
```